# I am not able to read blank cells from xlsx sheet in selenium using apache POI.(PS : I want to skip blank rows)

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

I am trying to identify a blank cell/row and skip it.

I am simply trying to read it using `getStringCellValue()` traditional way of POI.

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("c:\\abc.xlsx");
           Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
           Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

           int lastRow = sheet.getLastRowNum();
           System.out.println("Last row- "+lastRow);
           Row row = sheet.getRow(5);

           Cell cell = row.getCell(1);
           String value = cell.getStringCellValue();
           System.out.println(value);
```

I am getting Error on console as below:

```
Exception in thread "main"  java.lang.NullPointerException  at
test.Excel_test.main(Excel_test.java:31)
```

Comment: can you add the full stack trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blank cells in xlsx are typically set to null when using apache-poi, so you have to do a null check on your cell.

```
Cell cell = row.getCell(1);
if (cell != null) {
  String value = cell.getStringCellValue();
  System.out.println(value);
}
```